# How do you set the size of FontAwesome icon using CSS in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, angular-fontawesome

Per FontAwesome Usage Guide, you set the size of icons like so:

```
1. <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'coffee']" [classes]="['toolbar-icon']" size="2x"></fa-icon>
2. <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'coffee']" [classes]="['toolbar-icon']" transform="grow-8"></fa-icon>
```

The above methods work in the component view template.
However, I would like my icons to be responsive and would like it to resize in response to screen size changes.

I tried the following CSS settings:

```
#main-toolbar {
    background-color: rgb(165, 42, 42);

    // ... othe entries

    @media only screen and (min-width:480px){
        fa-icon {
            color: white;
            padding: 0px 64px;
            size: "lg";
            // transform: "grow-8";
        }      
      }
      
      @media only screen and (max-width:680px){
        fa-icon {
            color: yellow;
            padding: 0px 16px;
            size: "sx";
            // transform: "grow-2";
        }      
      }
}// #main-toolbar
```

The color and padding changes so the CSS is working. However, both **`size`** and **`transform`** does not work and are ignored. Also, setting the size of the icon in the CSS even without media query does not work.

Is there a way to set the size of the icon through CSS?

I am using FontAwesome v6.1.1 in Angular v14.0.4.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you use `font-size` instead?

Comment: @NicklasF Thanks for the super quick reply. It (font-size) works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Creating an answer just in case other people find this question and doesn't look in the comments.*

Since you style markup, you can use `font-size` to set the size of FontAwesome icons.

```
fa-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```